# How can I remove the gap between menu items and their dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I am working with a CSS/HTML dropdown that I found online as a starting point. I am tweaking it. When I make the browser smaller (I am using Chrome), there is a gap between the top row and the dropdown menu (see screenshot). Need some help on how to get rid of this gap.

[Here is the website](https://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) I am using as reference.

Thank you for your help!

What it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of dropdown menu]

What I want:

[image: Screenshot of what I want it to look like]

```css
body,
div,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol,
li,
dl,
dt,
dd,
img,
form,
fieldset,
input,
textarea,
blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #909eab url(bg.png);
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

nav {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #efefef;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a z-index: 2 property in "nav ul ul". It will make the dropdown come on top of the navbar.

Comment: most likely you did not specify the `position` rule. show your code here

Comment: CSS code added.

Comment: May you also insert your HTML?

Comment: HTML Added as well